# Ubuntu 18.04 GUI hangs after login

Tags: 18.04

My 18.04LTS was running fine but now the GUI hangs after logging in.

I then log in via command line and i am immeaditely presented with 'Can't open display'

xrandr throws the same error.

I've updated and upgraded, reinstalled ubuntu-desktop and unity and tried numerous other fixes all to no avail.

I can't see anything in syslog, and have no idea where the graphical config is stored as there is no xorg.conf either.

Any help appreciated - as this box is my virtualbox host and without the gui I can't use virtualbox properly.

Cheers

Comment: Can you tell us your computer's make, model and graphic card(s)?

Comment: Sorry my bad. It's based on an old ASUS M4A88T-M Motherboard with a Integrated ATI Radeon™ HD 4250 GPU, CPU is a Phenom II 1055t with 20gb RAM. As I said i use it as a VM host and it has been working fine. PC is still working fine via the command line, all vm's can be started manualy etc.

Comment: tbh I thought it might be to do with the integrated GPU so I've tried staring with an older kernel, but that doesn't help either.